# send commands to application with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Is it possible to send commands to a running script with a bash script in linux?

for example say that I have a python script with a couple of inputs, can I somehow use a bash script to handle these inputs?

Comment: "inputs" is a very vague term.

Comment: say raw_input() for python, Scanner(System.in) for java etc. Basically anything that makes the running process stop and wait for input from the terminal ;)

Comment: can you simply feed the standard input? if so, sure... `./bashscript | ./script.py`